# How to work with "FIFO" in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, fifo

Is there a standard collection in .NET that implements a FIFO stack?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

FIFO means first-in-first-out.  The data structure you're looking for is called a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx).

Comment: yes, or asker meant named pipes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe - named pipe (also known as a FIFO for its behavior)

Answer (score 23):

[FIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) means first in first out.  This is as opposed to [LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_(computing)) (or FILO as lucero pointed out). which is last in first out.

[A link comparing queues, stacks, and hashtables.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571.aspx)

You want to use a queue object for FIFO operations:

http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=66

MSDN link on [queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)

And a stack is used for LIFO operations: [Stack Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx)

Comment: Note that LIFO is also known as FILO. :-)

Answer (score 22):

Are you looking for the [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) class?

Comment: The accepted answer is outdated in favor of generic queue.